# Gradient turns to black

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I am using gradient in subview of UIView, after coming back to app by switching from some apps, the gradient becomes black. Don't know why, If anybody out there knows anything about this, help me out here.

Also i didn't subclass it programatically , directly put that in the UIView's class place in Storyboard itself (CustomGradientBlueView). Is that can be an issue.?
This is the code which am using for gradient ->

```
import UIKit

class CustomGradientBlueView: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // colour declarations


        let gradientColor1 = UIColor(red: 0.361, green: 0.145, blue: 0.553, alpha: 1.000)
        let gradientColor2 = UIColor(red: 0.263, green: 0.537, blue: 0.635, alpha: 1.000)

        // gradient decalarations

        let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [gradientColor1.CGColor,gradientColor2.CGColor], [0,1])

        //rectangle drawing

        var screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size

        let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0,0, screen.width, screen.height))
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        rectanglePath.addClip()
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0,0 ), CGPointMake(screen.width, screen.height), 0)

    }

}
```

Comment: why don't you use CAGradientLayer?

Comment: @MertBuran Can you please tell me how using CAGradientLayer would solve this issue.? What are the differences.?

Comment: "after coming back to app by switching from some apps, the gradient becomes black" Can you prove that, when you do that, `drawRect:` is being called?

Comment: @matt I was using this app, then i switched to Facebook app ( Lets say any app ). After using Facebook for a long time, I came back to my app for testing, suddenly it turned to black ( It is the starting page )

Comment: You didn't answer the question I asked.

Comment: @matt When the app becomes active, the view again appears right, its class is this CustomGradientBlueView class. So the view should call this class, so as this drwRect: method. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: I didn't ask what you think should happen. I asked what does happen. This is programming, not a guessing game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79012/discussion-between-alvin-varghese-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely in these lines:

```
var screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0,0, screen.width, screen.height))
CGContextSaveGState(context)
rectanglePath.addClip()
```

You are calling `CGContextSaveGState` without calling `CGContextRestoreGState` to balance it. That is very dangerous. If the context is maintained, which is perfectly possible, then you are saying `addClip` *again* with your previous clipping path already still in place - because you did not remove it with a balancing `CGContextRestoreGState` after drawing. Because of the nature of clipping paths, this causes you to end up with your whole view clipping, and your drawing is completely suppressed — hence the black view.

(It is not at all clear what you think you are doing with this clipping path in any case. There is no need to clip to the screen bounds, and accessing the screen bounds inside a view's `drawRect:` is a very odd thing to do. You might be happier just deleting those four lines altogether.)

Comment: You are correct matt, I read the document got the concept. Thanks for your valuable time :)

Comment: I changed the code with the code you suggested, Again that black background came up.